# Vagrant file resync: Vagrant Box does not update new content in text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I don't know real detailed specifics about vagrant settings but after I tried to resync my box when it started up. The vagrant box won't update the content I changed from my text editor to the box after the box is booted and before it is stopped and rebooted again. The command I used is below:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
```

I needed to resync because my rails server is running slowly on my machine locally. I was wondering:

1) Is this the behavior expected?

2) Are there other options to speed up my rails server so it doesn't take 1 second for every javascript file to load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your configuration you'll need:

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant rsync-auto
```

And at other terminal you can do:

```
$ vagrant ssh
```

And your app folder must be updated on virtual machine when you change at your develop environment.

But, I config my sync folders with [Vagrant basic usage](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html), it means without `type` option (let vagrant chose the best type, also it keeps sync):

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
```

And I use one terminal for vagrant stuff, with only these commands:

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
```

Answer 1) If you need use rsync, yes this is the behavior expected: folders will not been updated unless you start `vagrant rsync-auto` (I've tested this option)

Answer 2) You must expect a degradation on performance running a virtual machine, because you had limited some memory and cpu processors (unless you are running on Windows OS -I don't test it-).

Comment: Thank you. I expected the degradation of the speed, but the javascript pages were loading at a rate of one per second, now I get about 10 per second.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure:

1. `rsync.exe` on the path
2. The `rsync` or `rsync-auto` command is used to start vagrant, Without running these commands, Vagrant only syncs the folders on `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload`